# Very high MacBook Battery consumption on Sleep

Tags: macbook-pro, battery, unibody

I got an alleged trouble on my late 2008 Unibody MacBook.
I've never worried about this trouble because I thought that was a normal thing but I'm start thinking that it could be a trouble trouble.

My MacBook, on stop status, consumes around 30/35% of battery a day, is it normal??

I changed battery around 2 years ago and now it has 250 cycles and health is 93%.
Since I remember it has got this trouble and a format doesn't change things.

Is it normal or could it be a trouble?

Comment: Is stop status sleep or hibernate, or are you actually fully shutting it down? Either way, that amount of discharge is excessive, so you'll want to get the battery or Mac serviced.

Comment: Thank you! It's Sleep status, I don't like to turn it off and I don't know how to hibernate it, I'll try to contact Apple...or maybe I got to go Apple Store because my warranty has expired...

Answer (score 1):

Your option to get free support that is best would be to take it to the Genius Bar where they have some fairly fancy battery diagnostics. Any Apple Authorized Service center has access to similar tools from Apple.

As a consumer, you could check the System Information (System Profiler on older OS) and review Power details under Hardware:

```
  Charge Information:
    Charge Remaining (mAh): 6638
    Fully Charged:  Yes
    Charging:   No
    Full Charge Capacity (mAh): 6693
  Health Information:
    Cycle Count:    54
    Condition:  Normal
```

The above details are from a new MacBook Pro with an internal battery. It's in great shape. The below details are from a 14 month old MacBook Air where the battery is not going to make it to it's design life. I'll have to pay for the replacement since at the 1 year point when the warranty was in force, it was still "within spec"

```
  Charge Information:
    Charge Remaining (mAh): 1957
    Fully Charged:  No
    Charging:   No
    Full Charge Capacity (mAh): 4357
  Health Information:
    Cycle Count:    119
    Condition:  Normal
```

You might be able to tell if it's just a battery by inspecting your condition, cycle count and FCC - but these data are much more valuable when you have it logged every month of the Mac's life or can compare your values to thousands of other data points (which is presumably part of what Apple does in its diagnostics).

Comment: My full Charge Capacity is 3957 mAh, it's low but battery has already 2 years and and it's an old type of battery (from 2009 Apple uses new batteries that doubled autonomy) however it shouldn't justify this big battery consuption on sleep...I'll try to go to an Apple Store...

Comment: The old chemistry where you would be able to replace the battery on a plane yourself were statistically more likely to be not usable in 2.5 years and 300 full charge cycles. The new ones are statistically likely to be fully functional after 4.5 years and 1000 full charge cycles - but some (like my 11 inch Air will need replacing sooner than statistically likely).

Comment: 2 (or maybe 3) years ago battery was replaced for free (exceptionally!!!) under AppleCare, however, even if it's dying, I think that 3 days every on sleep to discharge it is too short time...

Comment: For Genius and diagnostic hardware is ok...he said that maybe trouble is due to double HD (I've got an SSD instead SuperDrive) but I don't think so or maybe there could be an app that keep working while Mac is sleeping (how it could be possible?!?)... So I think that the only way to improve this situation is to hibernate Mac for long sleeping...do you know how? (I tried some terminal strings but no one worked...)  Thank you!

Comment: Let's ask a second thread on how to disable sleep for your Mac. The genius may have not been clear - your Mac does not have PowerNap nor can anything run while in sleep mode. I would trust that the battery was within spec, but the rest of the advice seems suspect as reported.